# Match and copy column based in one column and partial match of another column

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have two data frames.

DATA

```
Name                Type            Code
gabapentine         Pharmaceutical  60142-96-3
Glyphosate          Pesticide       1071-83-6
Guanylurea          Pharmaceutical  141-83-3
hydrochlorthiazide  Pharmaceutical  58-93-5
```

Values

```
Name                Value           Code
gabapentine         0,2             60142-96-3
Glyphosate          1,8             1071-83-6
Urea                1,2             141-83-3
hydrochlorthiazide  0,5             58-93-5
```

I want to add the column `type` from `Data` to `Values`, by matching the columns `Name` and `Code`.

I know how to match with just one column, like this:

```
Values$type = Data$type[match(Values$Name, Data$Name)]
```

But now I want to take into account also the `Code`, since some names don't match.

Is there a way to do it in just one line, like

```
Values$type = Data$type[match((Values$Name, Data$Name) | (Values$Code, Data$Code))]
```

That didn't work for me, so I would like to know the right way to do it.

I tried using merge like in other questions

```
merge(Values, Data,all.x = TRUE)
```

but in `Guanylurea` from dataframe `Data` I get type `NA` when it should match `Urea` from dataframe `Values`. The result for that row would be `Type` equal to  `Pharmaceutical`, but the `Names` don't match exactly. So how can I add a partial match into functions `match` or `merge`? Or is there an alternative to these two?

Comment: `merge(Values, Data,all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: I tried that but in Guanylurea I get type NA and not Pharmaceutical, probably because the Names don't match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wide range of answers to this. I left four (`dfrx`), all using dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(Name = c("gabapentine", "Glyphosate",
                           "Guanylurea", "hydrochlorthiazide"),
                  Type = c("Pharmaceutical", "Pesticide", 
                           "Pharmaceutical", "Pharmaceutical"),
                  Code = c("60142-96-3", "1071-83-6",
                           "141-83-3", "58-93-5"))
df2 <- data.frame(Name = c("gabapentine", "Glyphosate",
                           "Guanylurea", "hydrochlorthiazide"),
                  Value = c(0.2, 1.8, 1.2, 0.5),
                  Code = c("60142-96-3", "1071-83-6",
                           "141-83-3", "58-93-5"))

dfr1 <- df2 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Type = df1$Type)
dfr2 <- df2 %>% 
  dplyr::bind_cols(Type = df1$Type)
dfr3 <- df2 %>% 
  dplyr::right_join(df1, by = "Name") %>% 
  dplyr::select(-Code.y) %>% 
  dplyr::rename("Code" = Code.x)
dfr4 <- df2 %>% 
  dplyr::right_join(df1, by = "Code") %>% 
  dplyr::select(-Name.y) %>% 
  dplyr::rename("Name" = Name.x)
```

```
> dfr4
                Name Value       Code           Type
1        gabapentine   0.2 60142-96-3 Pharmaceutical
2         Glyphosate   1.8  1071-83-6      Pesticide
3         Guanylurea   1.2   141-83-3 Pharmaceutical
4 hydrochlorthiazide   0.5    58-93-5 Pharmaceutical
```